# error: there are no arguments to 'at' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of at must be available

Tags: c++, templates, vector, compiler-errors, std

Noob here,

I'm trying to compile this segment of code from Bjarne Stroustrup's 'The C++ Programming Language' but CodeBlocks keeps throwing me this error.

The code is about range checking an array held in a vector function.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int i = 1000;

template<class T> class Vec : public vector<T>
{
public:
    Vec() : vector<T>() { }

    T& operator[] (int i) {return at(i); }
    const T& operator[] (int i) const {return at(i); }
    //The at() operation is a vector subscript operation 
    //that throws an exception of type out_of_range
    //if its argument is out of the vector's range.
};

Vec<Entry> phone_book(1000);

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

The errors returned are:

- there are no arguments to 'at' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'at' must be available
- note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated
- In member function 'const T& operator[] (int i) const':
- there are no arguments to 'at' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'at' must be available
- 'Entry' was not declared in this scope
- template argument 1 is invalid
- invalid type in declaration before '(' token

Can someone explain this to me?

Also, how would I implement this if I were to not use 'using namespace std;'

Comment: When inheriting from stl containers, you should be aware that they do not have a virtual destructor. This might cause problems when your subclass acquires resources that should be freed in its destructor.

Comment: The last question is trivial: either write `std::` in front of every name which came from `namespace std`, e.g. write `std::vector`  everywhere, OR write `using std::vector` once (Instead of `namespace`, just list all the individual names you use)

Comment: The MSVC++ version of this error is "function declaration must be available as none of the arguments depend on a template parameter"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Replace `at` with `vector<T>::at` or `this->at`.

Rules for how functions are looked up in templates are tighter now than when C++ was being originally designed.

Now, methods in dependent bases are only looked up if you `this->`, otherwise it is assumed to be a global function (or a non-dependent base/class local/etc).

This can help avoid nasty surprises in practice, where what you thought was a method call becomes a global one, or a global call becomes a method call.  It also allows earlier checking of template method bodies.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Yakk's answer, another solution would be to add

`using vector<T>::at;`

to `Vec` basically adding it to the list of looked up functions.

This way, `at()` can be used as usual without prefixing it with the base class type or `this->`.