# Why doesn't the using declaration in a class that derives from a template work as expected in some compilers?

Tags: c++, inheritance

If you derive from a class template, you have to qualify usages of base class members with either `Base::` or `this->`. This is understandable since a member of the base class is a template-dependent name. But there is a third option - you can use a `using` declaration. I decided to give it a try but with somewhat more convoluted hierarchy:

```
struct Gadget
{
    void gadge()
    {
    }
};

struct Base1
{
    Gadget g;
};

template<typename T>
struct Base2 : Base1
{
};

template<typename T>
struct Widget : Base2<T>
{
    using Base1::g;

    void foo()
    {
        g.gadge();
    }
};
```

But the problem is that `g.gadge` won't compile on some compilers. In particular, GCC 5.5.0 and GCC HEAD (8.0.1) will emit the following error message:

```
prog.cc: In member function 'void Widget<T>::foo()':
prog.cc:27:11: error: 'struct Base1' has no member named 'gadge'
         g.gadge();
           ^~~~~
```

On the other hand it compiles and works as expected with GCC 6.1.0, GCC 7.2.0, and all Clang versions that I've tried. Which compiler is right?

Comment: fyi it compiles with this change: `using Base2<T>::Base1::g;` ... now to workout why.

Comment: Might be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390663/error-there-are-no-arguments-to-at-that-depend-on-a-template-parameter-so-a).

Comment: @noma Not really. It's the same error message, but in that other question, it is clear that the error message is correct. Here, not so much.

Comment: "error: 'struct Base1' has no member named 'gadge'" looks like a pretty clear compiler bug to me, as `g` does not have type `struct Base1`. That doesn't actually prove the code is valid though.

Comment: @RichardCritten it also works with just `using Base2<T>::g`. Any idea how to find this bug in GCC's bug tracker?