# C++ protected function not visible from derived class

Tags: c++11, inheritance, protected

I'm trying to call initCapture() that's declared pure virtual in LexContext. I'm trying to call it indirectly in ArduinoLexContext by way of StaticLexContext which overrides it.

I get

```
LexContext.hpp:316:25: error: there are no arguments to 'initCapture' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'initCapture' must be available [-fpermissive]
```

Here's the code. I've omitted most of LexContext since it isn't relevant here. I've been at this all morning and I know the answer is staring me right in the face but I need another set of eyes on this.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
namespace lex {
  // represents a cursor and capture buffer over an input source
  class LexContext {
      int16_t _current;
      unsigned long int _line;
      unsigned long int _column;
      unsigned long long _position;
    protected:
      // reads a character from the underlying device
      // read() should return EndOfInput if no more data is available,
      // and Closed if the underlying source has been closed, where
      // applicable
      virtual int16_t read()=0;
      // called to initialize the capture buffer
      virtual void initCapture()=0;
    public:
      ...

  };
// represents a LexContext with a fixed size buffer
  template<const size_t S> class StaticLexContext : virtual public LexContext {
    char _capture[S];
    size_t _captureCount;
    protected:
      // initializes the capture buffer
      void initCapture() override {
        *_capture=0;
        _captureCount=0;

      }
    public:
      StaticLexContext() {
            
      }
      // the capacity of the capture buffer (not including the trailing NULL)
      size_t captureCapacity() override { return S-1; }
      // the count of characters in the capture buffer
      size_t captureCount() const override {return _captureCount;}
      // returns a pointer to the capture buffer
      char* captureBuffer() override {return _capture;}
      // clears the capture buffer
      void clearCapture() override {
        _captureCount = 0;
        *_capture=0;
      }
      // captures the character under the cursor if any
      // returns true if a character was captured.
      bool capture() override {
        if (Closed!=current() && EndOfInput != current() && BeforeInput != current() && (S - 1) > _captureCount)
        {
          _capture[_captureCount++] = (uint8_t)current();
          _capture[_captureCount] = 0;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }

  };
#ifdef ARDUINO
  // represents a fixed length LexContext for the Arduino built on the Arduino SDK's Stream class
  template<const size_t S> class ArduinoLexContext : public StaticLexContext<S> { 
        Stream* _pstream;
    protected:
        // reads a character from the stream
        int16_t read() override {
            if(!_pstream)
              return LexContext::Closed;
            return _pstream->read();
        }
    public:
      ArduinoLexContext() {
            
      }
        // initializes the lexcontext with a stream
        bool begin(Stream& stream) {
            _pstream = &stream;
            initCapture(); // compile error!
            return true;
        }
    };
#endif
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: there are no arguments to 'at' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of at must be available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390663/error-there-are-no-arguments-to-at-that-depend-on-a-template-parameter-so-a)

Comment: The problem isn't the protected-ness. The problem is that ArduinoLexContext derives from a template class. The compiler sees `initCapture();` and says, "Is this a member function derived from a base class? Or is it a global function? I'm going to assume it's a global function. Error: No global function called `initCapture`." (There might be a specialization `template<> StaticLexContext<0> { /* doesn't derive from LexContext, no initCapture method */ }`.) You need to help out the compiler and write `this->initCapture()` to say "The initCapture method is coming from my base class, trust me."

Comment: Raymond Chen - Perfect! That fixed it. I wonder why I've never run into this problem before? Oh well. Thanks so much!

Comment: It's possible that you've just been lucky and never derived from a templated type before, or at least if you did, you didn't stumble into this dark corner. It's also the case that compilers in the past were more forgiving of this error, but in more recent years they've gotten more strict, in order to improve standard-conformance.

Comment: It could be that compilers were more forgiving. I took a sabbatical from C++ for years to do .NET development w/ C# and C++ has grown a lot in the meantime! I'm excited about C++20. Coroutines! yay! I love that about C# (except it calls them iterators)

Answer (score 0):

Raymond Chen in the comments, folks. He's a hero.

> The problem isn't the protected-ness. The problem is that
> ArduinoLexContext derives from a template class. The compiler sees
> initCapture(); and says, "Is this a member function derived from a
> base class? Or is it a global function? I'm going to assume it's a
> global function. Error: No global function called initCapture." (There
> might be a specialization template<> StaticLexContext<0> { /* doesn't
> derive from LexContext, no initCapture method */ }.) You need to help
> out the compiler and write this->initCapture() to say "The initCapture
> method is coming from my base class, trust me."

– Raymond Chen